# Alter column name?

Tags: android, ormlite, alter-table

I have a table "Items" with different columns but I didn't asign a name in each column. Now I have different rows in this table and I would like to execute:

```
ItemsDao.queryBuilder().where().eq(Items.NAME, "computer").query();
```

But my column doesn't have name. I have tried to update my table with "alter table" but it doesn't work.

AnyBody know how I can add a name of my column without lost my information?

Thank you

Comment: @J. Steen. Ok. Sorry, I know it for the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Sorry, now I understand the question.  You are saying that you did not specify a `columnName = "..."` for each of your fields and you are having problems with `QueryBuilder` now because of this.

You don't need a `columnName` to get `QueryBuilder` to work although it is recommended.  You should be able to go back to fields and add a `columnName` static that matches your existing schema.  For example, if the field in the database is `"items"` then you just add the `columnName = "items"` to your Java field.  I don't believe Sqlite is case sensitive with regards to column names but it would be good to match the case as well.

But you don't need the `columnName`.  If you field name in the database is `"items"` then you should be able to do:

```
itemsDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("items", "computer").query();
```

If you edit your question to show your schema and the exception you are getting from `QueryBuilder`, I'll be able to respond more specifically.

---

I believe you should be able to do:

```
 dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `items` ADD COLUMN name VARCHAR;");
```

That doesn't work for you?  There is a section in the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) documentation about updating your schema under Android:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/upgrade-schema

To quote from it, you will need to change your database version when you make schema changes and then in your `onUpgrade(...)` method do something like:

```
Dao<Account, Integer> dao = getHelper().getAccountDao();
// change the table to add a new column named "age" 
dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN age INTEGER;");
```

Most likely you will be keying off the database version number do if they have version 1 you do X and Y but if they have version 2 you just do Y.  Something like that:

```
if (oldVersion == 1) {
  // we added the age column in version 2
  dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN age INTEGER;");
}
if (oldVersion < 2) {
  // we added the weight column in version 3
  dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN weight INTEGER;");
}
```

You *are* [limited by Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) on what you can do with `ALTER TABLE`.  Right now you can only rename a column or add a new column. See the docs for more details.

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to change the name, not add a column. I read that It is not possible to rename a column. I only want to use a column in a queryBuilder. If I haven't put a name in a column, I can't use querybuilder. Is it true?

Comment: Sorry @MARM.  I still don't understand.  Under sqlite you _can_ rename a column.  I've linked to the Sqlite page that shows what you can do. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: Oh I see @MARM.  Let me change my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the database, in your SQLiteOpenHelper you should:

- change database version
- override "onUpgrade" to make the changes you
  want
- change onCreate method, this way new users will have the good version of your database, not the old one

If there are big structural changes, in onUpgrade you copy the useful information in new database and drop the old database.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I have thought about this option but I thought  I had another option. Because I only need add a column's name for using querybuilder. When I created the table I didn't think about I would need to change my database. Thanks